# visual studio 2010 add reference version missing

Tags: visual-studio-2010

In VS2008 when I add a reference to a dll e.g log4Net I get the following in csproj

```
<Reference Include="log4net, Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1b44e1d426115821, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\..\lib\log4net\log4net.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
```

In VS2010 when I add a reference to a dll  for the first time e.g log4Net I get the following in csproj (i.e no version number etc)

```
  <Reference Include="log4net">
          <HintPath>..\..\lib\log4net\log4net.dll</HintPath>
   </Reference>
```

If I remove reference and add a second time the same details as in VS2008 is there (Version etc)

Anyone know why version number etc not present the first time I add a reference and why it is present on secound time reference added?

Answer (score 0):

Both snippets are equal - log4net assembly is not fully qualified

This seems to be a problem with the serialization but don't worry it should work

s

Comment: Muse, It works but I am woundering why the first time I add a version it does not include the version but if I add the second time it adds the version etc.

Comment: This is an issue with serialization of the .proj file and sometimes can be confusing. You can report it to MS